# Does BIRT 3.7.2 not support union data sets?

Tags: birt

I have styled a report using BIRT 2.5.0 and it had a data set containing a union of two selects.

This worked fine on BIRT 2.5.0.

We have now upgraded to BIRT 3.7.2 and the report shows a blank. On logging the sql query and running it on the database, it is returning data. But the data is not shown on the report presumably because the query is not compatible with BIRT.

I tried moving the query to the database by creating a view, however the change to the data set associated with the BIRT table is forcing me to recreate every element on the report file, which I want to avoid.

Does anybody have any tips on how we could make the 3.7.2 BIRT engine accept the union query like the older BIRT?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify you are doing a SQL union in one data set, not a joining multiple data sets in BIRT?

Comment: Yes, the union is in a single data set. It is not a joint data set. I tried to emulate the union using the joint data sets, but it looks like the joint data set doesn't support unions. Please do let me know if I am missing out on something here and there is indeed a way we can create the union using the joint data sets. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have 3.7.2 but I am using 4.2 and have used unions in my SQL.

Comment: You should make sure that your report doesn't contain some other error. Some of the errors will be shown only in the HTML output format. If the output is all blank, you should check the log files.

Comment: The log files, both the BIRT logs and the Report Engine logs do not show any errors.
I created a view using the same query. Instead of including the query in the report design, I called the view from the report design file and the report
was generated. I didn't have to make any other changes to the file, so I assume it was an issue with the way the query was handled by the BIRT rather than
an issue with the design file itself.

Comment: I assume you use scripted datasources? please configure your report to log/output the actual query send to the database and test that query by itself. I used unions in many BIRT versions, including 3.7.2